# Syntax to access variables in viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to retain a variable between postbacks, so I write an accessor to put it into viewstate. Which one of these is the best way to access it? Or is there a better option?

Option 1:

```
private int Status
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return (int)ViewState[@"__Status"];
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState[@"__Status"] = value;
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
private int Status
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState[@"__Status"] is int)
        {
            return (int)ViewState[@"__Status"];
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState[@"__Status"] = value;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Edit: I'm using C# 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the way that I tend to do it:

```
private int Status
{
  get { return (ViewState["MYSTATUS"] != null) ? (int)ViewState["MYSTATUS"] : 0; }
  set { ViewState["MYSTATUS"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Forgot about this method, I've used it before as well - trying to make my code more consistant.. As the viewstate variable will only be read / changed by this accessor, the explicit cast (if not null) should be fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, option 2 won't compile, but I think it's the right direction.   ;-)  Try not to use an exception for this.  Inspect the ViewState variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, is it reasonable to assume that null is the same as 0.  Why not use `int?` and the property type, then I think you could do something like this:

```
public int? MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["status"] as int?;

    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["status"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending upon the assumptions that the code is making, you might start seeing errors pop-up if you allow the value returned to be null, or you would have to add additional code to check for null.